# Specify amount of decimal places of an xs:decimal in an XML schema

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, wsdl, xsd

1. Is there a way to specify the amount of decimal places an `xs:decimal` should have in an XML schema?
2. Is there any way to control that using .NET's `Xml***` attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom type that extends decimal and specify the number of digits in `fractionDigits` like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="twoPlacesDecimal" id="twoPlacesDecimal">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:fractionDigits fixed="true" value="2" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

You can specify the data type for a property using `XmlAttribute(DataType = "value")` but unfortunately this only supports built-in data types.  From my reading of the source, if you include a custom data type you'll get an exception.

Comment: On an extra note: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112(v=vs.90).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d60kbz0(v=vs.100).aspx says that .NET ignores the fractionDigits restriction.