# Require a number of fractional decimal places with an XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to restrict the number of fractional decimal places of a number to exactly 2.

For example - 1.00 is valid, but 1, 1.0 and 1.000 are all invalid.

This is a similar question: [Specify amount of decimal places of an xs:decimal in an XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873038/specify-amount-of-decimal-places-of-an-xsdecimal-in-an-xml-schema)
and this was the answer provided:

```
<xs:simpleType name="twoPlacesDecimal" id="twoPlacesDecimal">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:fractionDigits fixed="true" value="2" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Unfortunately, this only limits the number of decimal places to 2, and allows numbers with zero or one decimal places.

Comment: Should have added that - only non-negative numbers should be accepted, but this is a trivial modification to the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've done this in the past, I used a regex matcher.  The regex you can use is something like this:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="exactlyTwoAfterDecimal">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
        <xsd:pattern value="^-?\d+\.\d\d$"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can force the number of decimal places to be exactly two using a regex, but is this wise? You're making life harder for anyone who generates documents that are supposed to conform to this schema. For example, they won't be able to use the default serialization produced by XSLT or XQuery, instead they will have to write their own. Isn't it better to change the spec to be a bit more liberal in what it accepts?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that with the `total` and `fractionDigits` restrictions alone, but it may be possible with a Regex pattern restriction, something like:

```
<xs:restriction base="decimal">
  <xs:pattern value="[+-]?\d+\.\d{2}"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Comment: If you want to make the decimal optional and allow values like 1 and 1.0 you need to make the decimal optional and allow a range like this, :

`<pattern value="\d+\.?\d{1,2}"/>`

Comment: @fourgablesguy your regex works for values like 10, 1.0, and 1.00 but it does not work for 0-9. Any input on how to get it to work for those values?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out.  The correct regex should be `\d+\.?\d{0,2}`.